# Can't access my nuxt 2 dev server on another devices (except of hosting one)

Tags: nuxt.js, webpack-dev-server

I use portable hotspot for internet access.

Devices:
Phone (hotspot) - site isn't accessible (err_connection_timed_out)
Laptop (development server) - site accessible
Another phone - site isn't site accessible(err_connection_timed_out)
Another laptop - site isn't site accessible(err_connection_refused)

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
ssr: true,
target: 'server', 

server: {
  port: 8080, // default: 3000
  host: '0.0.0.0', // default: localhost,
},
```

I can't get the source of problem, because static one worked nicely.

Comment: Are they both connected to the same network (like wifi)? What is the local IP of the machine hosting your project? Should be something starting by either `192.168` or `10.0`.

Comment: Yes, they are connected to one wifi. And yes, it's starts on 192.168

Comment: Alright, so you should be able to enter the IP of the machine running the server on your phone to have access to it. Don't forget the port!

Comment: I am sure that ip and port are correct, but still can't access

Comment: Then, it should work just fine. Double check the prefix. You could maybe also give that one a try: https://ngrok.nuxtjs.org/ Not sure if it may help.

Answer (score 1):

I am laughing, decided to check hotspotting internet from another phone and it's worked!!! That phone worse than first one)))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting the two devices to the same network

Comment: They are on the same.
First device is my laptop on which I coding and it's connected to hotspots wifi. And I have second phone, which connected to that wifi too. So they are on the same network

Comment: @IninsayY then it's a matter of finding out their local IP addresses on that network. Do you have access to the router of the house you're in?

Comment: It's only phone that using mobile internet and hotspoting it, so i am not sure i have so much access to it

Comment: @IninsayY yeah, clearly not a router in terms of flexibility. That should work too I guess but it depends on how it's done too.

Comment: But what should I check?

Comment: @IninsayY hard to say because I don't know your carrier and you probably don't have the same as mine (in Netherlands). Can't you try with a regular wifi router? It's possible that your phone just cannot make such routing and that one would be quite hard to debug without prior network knowledge on your side.

Comment: Thank you, yes, it's hard to fin da reason. Maybe it's fault of ssr, because another one was pretty ok when i used static. But I don't have router so can't check if it work with

Comment: At the end, the difference is just `target: 'static'` vs `target: 'server'` and you're still using `yarn dev` (or equivalent) to run it? That one should not make a difference normally. Sorry if I can't help further. @IninsayY

Comment: It's okey. But yes, it requires a server for deploing. But I am already hosting it on my laptop so it should work

Comment: `yarn dev` will spin a Node.js server during dev anyway, should not matter. You can't use SSG for that one? Then yeah, you'll need a paid VPS to host it mostly (Render/Railway can do that but with limits). Also, keep in my that your laptop is not really a viable "hosting" server, just nice for development/debugging but it will not deliver a good and reliable experience in the long run. @IninsayY

Comment: I use digital ocean auto deploy but it takes about 5 minutes so it's not the option for developing. But if I use it not for deploy but for developing will it work nice?

Comment: Yeah, your dev server is used for that purpose. Deploying for production should not be used for development purposes. Also, you should be able to access/preview your local currently running server on your phone. Your hotspot configuration is probably the main blocker here. Why do you want to have it on your phone anyway? Double check the responsive or some other reason? @IninsayY

Comment: I am frontender, so I should see how it will look like on real phone

Comment: @IninsayY yeah, I understand that browser's devtools may be limited + testing on a production website is far too slow. You could also use [this setup](https://raygun.com/blog/debug-android-chrome/), it's tedious and complex but is a workaround until you have a proper working router.

Comment: Oh, thank you. But it's more about seeing real size of elements. But I will try setup some vps

Comment: @IninsayY yeah I do understand that! The solution is still to use a router. Is it not possible? Simplest and cheapest solution so far. Otherwise, give a try to ngrok as [posted above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74396544/cant-access-my-nuxt-2-dev-server-on-another-devices-except-of-hosting-one/74396597?noredirect=1#comment131336720_74396544).

Comment: I am laughing, decided to check to hotspotting internet from another phone and it's worked!!! That phone worse than first one)))